# No free leases error with a Static CentOS SolusVM KVM slave

Tags: centos, dhcpd

I have a KVM SolusVM VPS slave with CentOS 7 that posts this message every couple seconds:

```
dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:25:90:cd:xx:xx via viifbr0: network 0.0.0.0/0: no free leases
```

I use a static IP on the server and for each VPS SolusVM makes on the slave. I think dhcpd is for dynamic IPs which I don't use that I'm aware of.

Two questions please :)

1. Can I disable DHCPD and if I can, how so?
2. If I can't disable it, can I stop it from reporting the free lease error?

Thanks, I have read 50+ articles but they are all on how to make dhcpd work. I'm trying to disable it or at least stop it from reporting errors.

Comment: You asked the same question two years ago! I don't know how to configure SolusVM, but although you say that you don't need DHCP, some devices in your network do. For example, the device with MAC address 00:25:90:cd:xx:xx, which is a Super Micro server. Therefore my answer to the first part of your first question is "it depends on the requirements in your network". If you can afford a test, disable it, then see if you get any complaints.

Comment: I don't know what distro runs on the Solus VMs, but I see Centos 7 mentioned in the documentation. If this is your setup, you can stop and disable the DHCPD by running `systemctl disable dhcp --now` on the server in question. Other distros name the DHCPD service differently, such as `systemctl disable --now isc-dhcp-server` on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: By default, logs are sent to the `rsyslog` facility LOG_DAEMON. You could configure `rsyslog` to write LOG_DAEMON messages somewhere else, but this would affect other services that use the same facility.